# If for an entire function $f(1)=i$ then find the value of $f(i)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let, $f(z)$ be an entire function such that $|f(z)|\le K|z|$ , for all $z\in \mathbb C$, for some $K>0$. If $f(1)=i$ then the value of $f(i)$ is:

(a) $1$

(b) $-1$

(c) $i$

(d) $-i$.

We know that, if $f(z)$ is entire function & $|f(z)|\le K|z|^{p}$ for some positive integer $p$ then $f(z)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $p$.

From this argument how we can solve the problem? Or any other technique to solve it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thus, $f(z)=w\cdot(z-1)+\mathrm i$ for every $z$ in $\mathbb C$, for some given $w$ in $\mathbb C$, and $f(0)=0$ hence $w=\mathrm i$, in particular $f(\mathrm i)=\mathrm i\cdot(\mathrm i-1)+\mathrm i=-1$.

Comment: Ok. Clearly the function is a polynomial of degree $1$, one condition is given, but there are two constants. So another condition is obtained from the given relation.i.e. the condition $f(0)=0$.

Comment: from the argument, $f(z)=az+b$ and if $f(1)=i$ implies $f(z)=az+(i-a)$. But after that how you are proceeding?? help me to do this..@did

Comment: @gloom Sorry but everything is in the answer. Or, you have to be much more specific about your problem (for example, do you understand why $f(0)=0$?).

Comment: No that's what I am asking.. Why f(0) =0?

Comment: @gloom You might want to reread the hypotheses on $f$, there are not so many.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is a linear polynomial as quoted by you.

So, $$f(z)=a_0+a_1z$$

and $|f(z)|\leq K|z|\implies |f(0)|\leq K|0|\implies f(0)=0$

Hence, $a_0=0$ and $f(1)=i\implies a_1=i$

therefore, $f(i)=a_0+a_1.i=-1$

Comment: Hmmm... Why copy a previous answer from 6 months ago?

Comment: Actually this is at least the *third* time you do something similar on the site. Be aware that mathematicians are notoriously touchy on attribution questions.